# Is there a word to describe a person who is always curious?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a word or phrase for describing a person who is always curious?
*Curiosiac*?

Example usage (as requested by a comment):

> The boy is such a ___, he asks questions all the time!

#### UPDATE

I appreciate all your answers, but my question was if there was any word - a noun - to describe a person of that kind, e.g. *maniac*, *lunatic*, *weirdo*, *nerd*, etc.

Comment: Perpetually curious?

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate, but it would be better if it included an example sentence of how you would want to use the word.

Comment: @Nathaniel I added an example as requested. Thanks.

Comment: a knowledge-monger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Inquisitive**, defined by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inquisitive)

> 1. given to inquiry, research, or asking questions; eager for knowledge; intellectually curious:
>
> *"an inquisitive mind"*
>
> 2. unduly or inappropriately curious; prying

Answer (score 4):

Maybe someone who is "inquisitive"?

> **Inquisitive (adj):** wanting to discover as much as you can about things, sometimes in a way that annoys people.
>
> [[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inquisitive)]

Answer (score 2):

Inquisitive is a good answer but also try [pysmatic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pysmatic)

> Very questioning.

Also, [quidnunc](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quidnunc)

> a person who seeks to know all the latest news or gossip

Comment: Just to add sth, quidnuc, from Latin, literally means "what now".

Answer (score 0):

"Insatiable curiosity" is the term I've most often seen used in this sense.

There are nouns such as [polymath](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polymath) which refer to people who know about lots of diverse topics, but they don't directly imply an insatiable curiosity.